# Confusing result from raw_input() in Python

Tags: python

I'm having problems with the "operator" variable. So far I have only tried +. It doesn't seem to register and I can't figure out why. i'm using the online python interpreter on repl.it because I'm having problems with my computer.

EDIT: I should probably add that I just started learning Python (I had some Java experience but it was years ago). I'm trying to create a simple text calculator.

```
    restart=raw_input("to restart calculations enter \'true\'")

    #if restart == "true":
        #stuff

    numone=raw_input("Enter the first number: ")
    operator = raw_input("Enter the operator(+,-,*,/):")
    operator = str(operator)
    numtwo=raw_input("Enter another number: ")
    print("operator: " + operator)

    if operator== '+':
        answer=numone+numtwo
        print(answer)
        print("test")

    if operator == "-":
        answer=numone-numtwo
        print(answer)

    else:
        print("something went wrong")

    #if operator == "*":
```

Comment: What's the problem?... Note that you don't need `operator = str(operator)`.

Comment: I guess this is homework? Otherwise why don't you simply use eval?

Comment: Its not homework. I'm just starting out and didn't even know about eval lol. I'll look at it.

Comment: You could also use a while loop with the raw_input, to test if it is an integer, this way you always get integer values with the input.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're concatenating two strings, you should cast to `int` before:

```
answer = int(numone) + int(numtwo)
```

Why? Because `raw_input` reads the input as string.

Answer (score 2):

Give `elif` to the second statement

since user give `'+'`

first `if` statment excutes but in next statement it `fails` and go to the `else` so for `+` you get `two result` both addition and something wrong

and also you need to convert the `operands` to `integer`

one more thing while converting to integer you need check right conditions for integer else it will give error

```
numone=raw_input("Enter the first number: ")
operator = raw_input("Enter the operator(+,-,*,/):")
operator = str(operator)
numtwo=raw_input("Enter another number: ")
print("operator: " + operator)

if operator== '+':
    try:        
        answer=int(numone)+int(numtwo)
        print(answer)
        print("test")
    except  ValueError:
        print "one of the operand is not integer"

elif operator == "-":
    try:
       answer=int(numone)-int(numtwo)
       print(answer)
       print("test")
    except  ValueError:
       print "one of the operand is not integer"        

else:
    print("something went wrong")
```